# Почему изображения после загрузки на сервер слегка меняют цвет?

Tags: php, ubuntu, prestashop-1.7

Есть сайт, строящийся на CMS PrestaShop последней версии.

Также есть чистый сервер на Ubuntu 16 LTS, на который поставлена ISPManager.

Руками на самом сервере ничего не делал.

Сейчас обнаружил, что абсолютно все изображения, загруженные через админку CMS (логотип, изображения в категориях, изображения в товарах, баннеры и так далее) как-будто имеют на себе слой слегка серого цвета.

Вот примеры:

- [Оригинал](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6IAl.jpg)
- [После загрузки на сайт](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOU4g.jpg)

С чем это может быть связано и как это можно исправить?

Comment: url сайта ннада.

Comment: А зачем url? Изображения имеют разный размер. Видимо при загрузке идет ресайз с изменением качества.

Comment: + джпег съедает

Comment: @Visman и как это побороть, не подскажете? Изображения в jpeg с максимальным качеством. При загрузке ресайс имеется - ну это классика. А вот изменение цвета - такое я замечаю впервые. Особенно в данном случае идет загрузка фотографий материалов на сайт, а там цвет важен.

Comment: @Colibri, jpeg при пересохранении даже с максимальным качеством теряет это качество. Если сами сохраняете фото в фотошопе, то попробуйте при сохранении в jpeg включить галку **Преобразовать в sRGB**.